# .net XML deserialization - track which properties have been deserialized

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I've got a legacy system that begins by reading config classes from an XML file, then performing some various other logic on the resulting object after they've been deserialized.

In writing a tool to migrate old config files to the new format, I'm trying to go through the regular serialization process, but will need to keep track of only those properties which have been deserialized from the XML file.  Is there a way to hook into the XML serializer to trigger some event for each property that it deserializes?

Consider a class like the following:

```
public class UrlPrefs{
    public string LoginUrl = "http://default.com/login";
    public string LogoutUrl = "http://default.com/logout";
    public int MaxFailedLogins = 3;
}

// ...

public UrlPrefs ReadUrlPrefs(string fileName){
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UrlPrefs));
    using(var stream = new StreamReader(fileName)){
        UrlPrefs ret = (UrlPrefs)ser.Deserialize(stream);
        return TouchUpPrefsFromDB(ret); // Gets another layer of overrides from the database...
    }
}
```

The following would be a valid UrlPrefs.xml:

```
<UrlPrefs>
    <LoginUrl>http://customer.com/login</LoginUrl>
    <LogoutUrl>http://customer.com/logout</LogoutUrl
</UrlPrefs>
```

Notice that MaxFailedLogins is not set in the XML, so will default to 3.
So, I'd like to monitor the serializer to know that LoginUrl and LogoutUrl are the only ones that were touched.

Note: I know I could feasibly convert those to properties and do some logic in the setter method, but we're talking about hundreds of properties in the real world, not just the 3 from my example, so I'm trying to avoid that kind of tedium.

Comment: Have you looked into AOP (like PostSharp) - that would let you inject code into the property setters en-masse.

Comment: Also, using the XML document functions may be the way to go, rather than the serializer.